# A function to remove characters in a string from another string

Tags: c, string

I am in an introductory computer programming class and this is the last question on the assignment and any help would be appreciated.  I know how to remove a character from a string, but I can't figure out how to take characters from one string and remove them from another string.  The call to the function looks like this:

```
void removeChars(char *str, const char *cs)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using C by the way.

Comment: first off C != C#

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to remove a single character from a string, then removing all of the characters in one string from another is just as easy. You just need to re-use your first function but call it for each character in string to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use substring search library function - "strstr" should work for you